# Find Multiple hits of the search value across all columns & rows of a table and return a list of the results from the 1st column of the table

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, lookup

I have a spreadsheet that holds a list of offices in the 1st column. Each column after this holds the list of Postcodes that this office covers (only the 1st part, ie se3). Some of the postcodes are covered by multiple offices and as such the postcode will appear in more than one row. However due to the way the Data is sent to me they do not end up in the same column. I am using Excel 2016.

I need to return a list of offices that cover the searched postcode. I am able to return the 1st office found, by using:

```
{=IFNA(IF(ISBLANK($L$7),"",INDEX('[WORKBOOK2.XLSX]SHEET1'!$A$3:$A$244,MAX(IF('WORKBOOK2.XLSX'!SHEET1[#DATA]=$L$7,ROW('WORKBOOK2.XLSX'!SHEET1[#DATA]))))-2)),"")}
```

I cannot however work out how to get the 2nd or 3rd office to be returned.

if anyone can help it would be appreciated

While i cannot provide a true example of the workbook i am using due to sensitive data, below is an example, but the actual worksheet is approx 244 rows by 75 columns.

[Small example of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO78j.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using `=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$10,SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10,ROW($B$3:$H$10),""),1))),"")`
in D15 and

`=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$10,SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10,ROW($B$3:$H$10),""),2))),"")`

In D16 (etc) resolved the issue

Thanks JohnSUN

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

For me works fine the formula of the form
`{=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13);"";INDEX($A$1:$A$10;SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10;ROW($B$3:$H$10);"");{1:2:3})));"")}`

or perhaps
`{=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$10,SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10,ROW($B$3:$H$10),""),{1;2;3}))),"")}`

or
`{=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$10,SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10,ROW($B$3:$H$10),""),ROW(A$1:A$3)))),"")}`

It return **Office A** and **Office G** for **AB1** or **Office E** and **Office F** for **S12**

[image: Result]

Comment: i have adjusted your formula to fit my sheet 

=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($D$13),"",INDEX($A$3:$A$10,SMALL(IF($D$13=$B$3:$H$10,ROW($B$3:$H$10),""),{1:2:3}))),"")


but it is hanging at:  {1:2:3}  and wont let me enter the formula. Are the separators supposed to be Colons as your formula above shows Semi colons instead of commas

Comment: Yes, perhaps this separator [**is a semicolon**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for you (this setting depends on the localization, I really have a backslash and a colon)

Comment: You can replace it with **ROW(A$1:A$3)**, it is a little longer, bat same